# React CkEDITOR Image upload to django backend

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have used React as fronted and DRF for API and Django as backend. I have a ckeditor in React and want to upload a image from ckeditor. How can I acheive that

Answer (score 0):

you should create upload adapter for your component, CKEditor has explained its features very good, check it out [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/image-upload.html) and [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/upload-adapter.html)

also, you can use [this package](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/upload.html) to handle this feature